# Add image on backFields and add background image on front side of PKPass in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, passbook

I am working on creating passes I have two following queries.

- How to add icon image like attached image with some text and also tried with following dictionary on JSON file?
- How to add background image on front side of card? I was able to add background image but then I'll have to change to card and then strip image become hide, right now I am using "coupon" type.I have to use coupon type card.[image]

  "backFields":[
                {
                "key" : "rewards",
                "label" : "REWARDS",
                "value" : "8th coffee FREE",
                }]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do either of these things.

The structure of passes is very strict. You can find the documentation on the structure [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW45). If you look at figure 3-3 (Layout of a coupon) you will see the only option for an image on the front side of the pass is the strip image. You can only change the background color.

As for putting images on the back side of the pass, this is not possible. You may only add text to the backside. From the same page:

> The Back of the Pass Provides Additional Space for **Text**
>
> ...
>
> The back of the pass gives you a place to put information that is too long to fit on the front of the pass, extra information that isn’t as important, and general information that may be helpful for your users. Examples of back fields include terms and conditions, the full address of a venue, your customer service phone number, and the URL for your website.